# Wildfly Modules thread safety

Tags: jboss, thread-safety, wildfly

I want to place one commonly used jar in Wildfly's module, but I'm concerned with thread-safety.
How are modules linked with the application? 

Is it similar to shared libraries on an OS level, i.e. every application that loads a module places its module in its own address space and
what code can go in a module?

Answer (score 1):

All classes from all modules are running within the same JVM. Means, there is no memory isolation, no difference in thread safety compared to other Java applications (standalone, Java EE, Spring). It is your responsibility to keep your module thread safe.

Comment: But, suppose that I use this module as a library that would be included in each application that requires it. I suppose that in deploy time, classes from the library would be loaded for each deployment(application) separately, which means every application would have those classes in its own address space. Am I right? Or would different classloaders (for each application) know those are the same classes and decide not to load them twice?

Comment: Each module has its own classloader.

Comment: @ctomc I know that, as can be read from my comment. Your comment adds no value to the topic.

Comment: each application will have the module classes available through the unique module classloader.So you have only one instance of the class loaded.